# Oxymoronic soundtrack — mismatch audio to visuals

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or a turn of phrase to describe a situation whereby the music or a soundtrack does not go with the visuals of a film at all. This is to perhaps make it more poignant and create more of an emotional impact because of the sheer contrast of the ill-fitting music.

E.g. really happy cheerful music in a violent war movie.

Some adjectives I have considered so far include:

> - disjointed
> - contrasting
> - contradictory
> - out-of-sync
> - antithesis of each other
> - (oxymoronic?)

Perhaps there isn't a single word or phrase to describe this, but wondered if anyone had any other helpful suggestions or phrases in mind.

Comment: Among the alternatives, *out-of-sync* comes the closes to the technical terms.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the best phrase / word to describe two juxtaposed circumstances that are ridiculously discordant is (totally) *incongruous*.

Comment: Why not simply use "discordant"?

Answer (score 2):

How about **dissonance**? It conjures up the appropriate sense of 'ick' and 'what the heck??!' in my head from having music that's got a completely opposite emotional timbre to the video footage.

Comment: NOAD lists a definition for _dissonance_ that seems especially supportive of your suggestion; it reads: _"a tension or clash resulting from the combination of two disharmonious or unsuitable elements"_. [Other online dictionaries](http://www.wordnik.com/words/dissonance) use definitions that seem to focus more on a lack of harmony within the music itself, but the word is widely used in other contexts nonetheless (such as [_cognitive dissonance_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance)). I find this to be a very good candidate.

Comment: @J.R., While aptly adaptable to this meaning, dissonance, as you mentioned, has a very specific meaning to musicians and is even quite beautiful to some of us.

Answer (score 1):

@Edwin's "incongruous" is good, but maybe a bit stuffy.  How about just:

[Inappropriate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Inappropriate?s=t)

> not appropriate; not proper or suitable: an inappropriate dress for the occasion.

Others:

Unfitting, unsuitable, silly, inept, irreverent, idiotic, misunderstood, over-stylized, hipster, or [this](http://thesaurus.com/browse/inappropriate).

You can really express your opinion on their misuse, vs. just implying that it is "*not working for you*".

Answer (score 1):

***lip-flap***
Wikipedia entry on [Audio to video synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_to_video_synchronization) lists two terms for **the lack of it**: ***lip sync error, lip-flap***.

See also:
*[Experts' Experts: Lip-Flap — Why your expensive TV's audio and video are out of sync](http://www.bookofjoe.com/2012/03/experts-experts-lip-flap-why-your-expensive-tvs-audio-and-video-are-out-of-sync.html)*

For an adjective, you would in all possibility, use
(A/V) ***unsynced***

Answer (score 0):

@Edwin and @ipso

Thanks to both for very good suggestions. I have also found another film specific term of "*counterpoint*". Although usually referring to classical music, it can be used to mean a contrasting element. (see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterpoint)

Comment: Ah – perhaps **contrast** would work for what you’re going after.  *“The inappropriate music served as contrast to the image.”*  “Counterpoint” may or may not work, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

***"solecistic" soundtrack*** - based on solecism, particularly definition #3, below, from Dictionary.com

> solecism[ sol-uh-siz-uh m, soh-luh- ] noun
>
> 1. a nonstandard or ungrammatical usage
>
> 2. a breach of good manners or etiquette.
>
> 3. any error, impropriety, or inconsistency.